# getValue() in google script returns false after running function that adds a google form entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've created a form in google sheets that after clicking the Send button it creates a google forms entry (by loading a url) with the data that was typed in on the sheet. The script looks like this:

```
function registerTest() {
  var ws_MAIN = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var url = ws_MAIN.getRange("U1").getValue();
  if(url=="") return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("ERROR: Incomplete data");
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function(){google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Unable to register automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Please clic here</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410)</script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth(90).setHeight(1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Registering..." );
  
  var n,check;
  for(n=0;n<5;n++){
    check = ws_MAIN.getRange("O31").getValue(); //to check if form entry was created
    if(check==true){
      deleteData();
      return;
    }
    Utilities.sleep(500);
  }
}
```

On cell "O31" I have this simple function "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B4,FormResponses!D:D,0))" that shows true if the form id is found. So var check should return true after the first part of the function runs (and as I'm seeing it on the screen on the sheet change to TRUE), I've tried using Utilities.sleep and crating loops to check if the value changes after reading it several times but it doesn't work and I don't know why. If anyone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it very much, I'm relatively new to coding. Thank you.

Comment: Kindly share a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to change the last part of the code this way:

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
var check = ws_MAIN.getRange("O31").getValue(); //to check if form entry was created
if (check == true) deleteData();
return;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, that's exactly what I was looking for, a way to "refresh" the data before continuing with the script, I just didn't know how to look for it. Sorry it took a bit long to report back, I have a deadline with a project I'm working on. This definitely helps!